# Unable to validate data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi am currently using laravel to code out my website where I've created a form with different inputs however facing problems with validation especially with FORM inputs that are stored in an array.

[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lSmz.png)

Error messages are supposed to display when there is no input entered into the form when submitted, however only the StudentName and RoomNumber are the only ones being validated. With that being said these 2 are the only inputs not in an array.

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ECQx.png)

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/180Od.png)

Why is this happening for the data stored in the array.
Thank you

Comment: Please don't screenshot the source code, copy and paste it

Answer (score 0):

You forgot underscores

```
Form::text('Student_Name'
Form::text('Student_Grade'
Form::select('Student_Department'
Form::select('Dormitory_Name'
Form::number('Room_Number'
```